# How to make primary key a combination of a primary key in another table and 2 letters in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a table `bus-fleet` with a primary key column `bus-fleet-code`.

I have another table `bus` with primary key `bus-code`, it is stated that a `bus-code` is a `bus-fleet-code` + 2 letters.

How can I achieve `bus-code` as a combination of `bus-fleet-code` + 2 letters?

Comment: Hello, you should mark an answer if your question is answered. You do it by clicking the check-mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the primary key a composite of the code and fleet:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [bus-fleet] (
    fleet varchar(55) NOT NULL,
    code varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    primary key (fleet, code)
);
```

Comment: I have two tables, bus-fleet and bus.....in the table bus, bus-code is a combination of bus-fleet-code + two letters

Comment: @RefiloeRaselane, you actually have 2 separate attributes to form the composite primary key in a properly normalized database design. That allows you to also create a foreign key to guarantee only valid bus-fleet-code values. If your users want to view the PK in a single column, concatenate them on the app side or T-SQL. You could also add a computed column `bus_code_key AS fleet + code`.

Comment: I tried to concatenate those 2 letters but it did not. The reason is that I have separate tables.

Comment: @RefiloeRaselane, your question is unclear. I understand `bus-code` is the primary key of the `bus` table so doesn't it already have `bus-fleet-code` and the 2-letters concatenated? If not, what is the source of those 2 letters?

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on not creating another table as @TimBiegeleisen has suggested, this is a possible solution for you.

```
SELECT 
    [bf].[bus-fleet-code],
    [b].[bus-code]
FROM 
    [bus-fleet] bf
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [bus] b ON [bf].[bus-fleet-code] = LEFT([b].[bus-code], LEN([b].[bus-code]) - 2)
```

*Edit:
Here's a complete, runnable, example.*

```
CREATE TABLE bus_fleet (
  bus_fleet_code nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
  bus_fleet_name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE bus (
  bus_code nvarchar(12) NOT NULL,
  bus_name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO bus_fleet (bus_fleet_code, bus_fleet_name) VALUES 
('1000', 'Fleet 1000'),
('2000', 'Fleet 2000'),
('3000', 'Fleet 3000')

INSERT INTO bus (bus_code, bus_name) VALUES 
('1000AA', 'Bus 1000AA'),
('1000AB', 'Bus 1000AA'),
('2000AA', 'Bus 2000AA'),
('3000AA', 'Bus 3000AA')

SELECT 
    [bf].[bus_fleet_code],
    [bf].[bus_fleet_name],
    [b].[bus_code],
    [b].[bus_name]
FROM 
    [bus_fleet] bf
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [bus] b ON [bf].[bus_fleet_code] = LEFT([b].[bus_code], LEN([b].[bus_code]) - 2)
```